# Restore the state of a table created by a for loop

Tags: android

Hi guys i created a dynamic table using tablelayouts by adding the values i put in edit texts in a different activity.  I use a for loop to continually add values to the table.  So my question is how is it possible to save the values and the whole activity with this values in them and be able to continue from the point where the activity was stopped because when the activity is exited the values are lost and so this is a big problem.  Thank you in advance for any response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: How can i use the sharedpreferences for retaining the information of the for loop of the newly added textviews dynamically thanks!